# Refresh data in GridView on DropDownList selected index change

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have ASP webpage with `GridView1` connected to `SqlDataSource1`, and `DropDownList1` that makes influence on `SqlDataSource1` SQL script.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="terminalLog.aspx.cs" Inherits="_2013web.terminalLog" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Id" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Height="95px" OnLoad="DropDownList1_Load" OnTextChanged="DropDownList1_TextChanged" Width="481px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:logsConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ClientID], [Msg], [LogLevel], [Date] FROM [logs] WHERE ([ClientID] = @ClientID) ORDER BY [Date]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="80" Name="ClientID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="2104px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientID" HeaderText="ClientID" SortExpression="ClientID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Msg" HeaderText="Msg" SortExpression="Msg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LogLevel" HeaderText="LogLevel" SortExpression="LogLevel" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:logsConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id] FROM [clients] ORDER BY [Id]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

I need to show new data when `DropDownList1` new value is selected.

I think I need something to be written there:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.Update();
}
```

`SqlDataSource1.Update();` not helps.

What should be executed in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` ?

Comment: GridView1.DataBind() if you want to refresh the grid.

Comment: `DropDownList1` is wired to `SqlDatasource1`'s control parameter and the GridView property: `<asp:GridView ... DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` will cause the gridview to databind on every postback.  No code required as Aria said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no need write any code, based on your question `AutoPostBack` of your `DropDownList1` is `True` and when the selected value is changed your GridView will updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```